# How to prevent \n to from being translated to \r\n on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, line

I am using Windows 10 and Strawberry Perl

It is well know that the line terminator in Linux is `\n`, and in Windows is `\r\n`.

I found that, on my computer, files of Linux type will automatically transform to windows type `\r\n` after a replacement operation like

```
perl -i.bak -pe "s/aaa/bbb/g" test.txt
```

But this is not what I want, and it seems unreasonable. I would like to know if this is a Strawberry Perl issue, or another factor?

How can I leave the line terminator unaffected on Windows?

Comment: *"But this is not what I want, and it seems unreasonable"* Why do you think it unreasonable for perl to assume that it should read and write standard Windows files on a Windows systemunless you say otherwise?

Comment: Hi, @Borodin. Because perl done something implicitly, and I don't see any problem using `\n` exclusively as newline on windows. Actually I set unix format as notepad++ default which is my main editor. This is critical for me, because I work on windows desktop and linux server at the same time.

Comment: *"I don't see any problem using \n exclusively as newline on windows"* You'll have to take that up with Microsoft. Windows has used CR LF as the line terminator since the very first version. Just because you would prefer it to work a different way doesn't mean it's a good idea for the whole world to change around you.

Comment: Hi, @Borodin. Thank you for reply. My experience is that in linux many program will have problem with input file contain \r. I recall that I actually didn't use command line things that much on windows. Maybe I am wrong. Could you give an example which \n will cause problem in windows program?

Comment: *"Could you give an example which \n will cause problem in windows program?"* It depends entirely on how each application is written, and you would have to test everything on Windows to make sure that it works correctly without CR characters in the data. The likely effect is that a program will find no line terminators in the file and so will read the whole thing as a single record. I know for a fact that Notepad will be unable to read the file properly, and there are probably many other examples. That will have many effects depending on the application, but most things will not work at all.

Comment: *"I actually didn't use command line things that much on windows"* Then it sounds like you're not really in a position to branch out and use a non-standard file format on Windows. I suggest you should wait until you're much more familiar with the system before making such an extreme decision.

Comment: Perhaps you need to as a question on Stack Overflow: "Is there any problem with keeping all my files in Linux format on a Windows system?". You should also read [*Do not change Linux files using Windows apps and tools*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

Comment: Re "*Could you give an example which \n will cause problem in windows program?*", Try loading the file in `notepad`

Answer (score 2):

This is standard behavior of Perl on Windows (to convert `\n` to `\r\n`).

You can get around it by using [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html), which prevents Perl from doing the automatic line-ending conversion.

Your command would then be changed to look like this. It tells `binmode` to write to `STDOUT` and then that output has to be redirected to another file. The following command should do what you want (though not in place):

```
perl -pe "BEGIN{ binmode(STDOUT) } s/aaa/bbb/g" test.txt > newtest.txt
```

Comment: Hi, birryree. Thank you so much for answering. But solutions sounds complicated. I forgot to ask why perl forces newline to \r\n on windows? It doesn't make sense, the command I provide to perl is nothing related to newline operation, it just done unnecessary stuff for me. And by the way, how to do inplace replacement?. I found -i.bak doesn't work.

Comment: @user15964 It's a Perl behavior that shows itself on Windows. Basically, when writing to a file on Windows, Perl will convert `\n` to `\r\n` unless you use `binmode` and do what I show in my answer. You don't have to explicitly do anything for this automatic line-ending conversion to happen. Doing it in place with `binmode` is something I don't know how to do (and I don't have a running Windows set up so I couldn't test that anything I did there was correct).

Comment: PowerShell needs operators for legacy piping and file redirection that simply set up the standard I/O handles for programs without inserting the shell as a middleman.

Comment: BTW, file I/O is binary in the Windows API, i.e. it doesn't do LF <=> CRLF conversions. It's Microsoft's C runtime that does that conversion for files opened in text mode. Does Perl use the CRT's POSIX compatibility API, or does it use the Windows API directly? In Python 3.x we still use the CRT, but just its low I/O functions (e.g. `_wopen`, `_write`) with all low I/O file descriptors opened in binary mode; buffered and text I/O objects are layered over the raw layer. Nonetheless we still default to using CRLF in text mode on Windows because it's the platform standard.

Comment: @eryksun: Please don't make this even more confused. What you say is very wrong; **CRT** is *not* a recognised abbreviation for the Microsoft C Run Time Library; and there's no reason to involve Python here. The only software that translates CR LF to and from LF is the perl compiler. The MS C run time library uses CR LF only to delimit lines of text. If you think you can help the OP then please write your own answer.

Comment: @Borodin, birryree said "prevents Windows from doing the automatic line-ending conversion", and *Windows* does no such thing. BTW, "CRT" is a very common abbreviation for "C runtime", and I already clarified the context that I was talking about Microsoft's C runtime, which does LF =>CRLF translation when files are opened in text mode.

Comment: @eryksun: You're making things worse. *"Microsoft's C runtime, which does LF =>CRLF translation when files are opened in text mode"*. Again, this is completely untrue. The MS C run time library doesn't do any translation at all. Please stop spreading misinformation just to hide your embarrassment. Python does the same thing as Perl, so you should be familiar with this.

Comment: @birryree: I think the mention of PowerShell detracts from your answer. The OP hasn't mentioned PowerShell at all, and it's safe to assume that they're working with a cmd window.

Comment: @Borodin, I suppose you've never used the CRT's low I/O layer in one of its *translated* text modes, e.g. `_O_TEXT`, `_O_WTEXT`, `_O_U16TEXT`, or `_O_U8TEXT`. These modes not only translate LF to CRLF when writing strings to a file, but also for `FILE` streams text mode interprets "\x1A" (i.e. Ctrl+Z) as EOF when reading a file. The sources for the C runtime are published, so this is not a debatable matter.

Comment: @eryksun: Please stop it. You wrote *"Microsoft's C runtime, which does LF =>CRLF translation when files are opened in text mode"* and said nothing about ***using the low-level IO layer in a translated text mode***. That's also clearly not what you meant at the time. You were wrong; stop digging.

Comment: @Borodin, all text modes in Microsoft's CRT are *translated* text modes. The high-level `FILE` stream API (e.g. `fopen`, `fread`, `frwrite`) is layered on top of the "low I/O" layer (e.g. `_open`, `_read`, `_write`), which provides basic POSIX compatibility and maps POSIX file descriptors (e.g. 0, 1, 2) to Windows File handles. Windows itself (e.g. `CreateFile`, `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`) implements binary I/O; it does no LF => CRLF translation.

Comment: @Borodin, I made a small correction to birryree's answer and then asked a question about how Perl is implemented to see to what extent this is 3rd party behavior (i.e. based on Microsoft's C runtime text mode, which Python 2 also uses) vs specifically chosen behavior. For the latter I gave an example from my own experience with Python 3's decision to default to translating newlines to CRLF on Windows even though it no longer uses the CRT's text mode.

Comment: @user15964, Strawberry Perl is a Windows distribution, so by default it does the right thing for Windows files.  There might well be a distribution corresponding to whichever bash you're using, or you could build one from source if you wanted.

Comment: @Borodin, eryksun is absolutely right about the Microsoft CRT, it does indeed do CRLF/LF translation.  Perl might or might not be using this functionality but it definitely exists.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: The C run time library `stdio` provided by Microsoft does no character conversion; it can't because its behaviour is part of the C standard. Yes, there are libraries that do convert between CR LF and LF—I could write one myself—but they're completely irrelevant because Perl doesn't use them, and this is a question about Perl. At build time, Perl does its best to replace even `stdio` by its own faster library, so not even `stdio` is relevant. What is *"beside the point"* is that there are other libraries somewhere that alter the characters read from a file.

Comment: @Borodin thank you for the edit and suggestions - I removed the Powershell portion as it was probably a little confusing and unnecessary.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: What **eryksun** originally wrote is *" 
BTW, file I/O is binary in the Windows API, i.e. it doesn't do LF <=> CRLF conversions. It's Microsoft's C runtime that does that conversion for files opened in text mode"*, and that's incorrect and misleading.

Comment: @Borodin, the C run time library `stdio` provided by Microsoft *does* do character conversion.  See [fopen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx): "In text mode, carriage return–linefeed combinations are translated into single linefeeds on input, and linefeed characters are translated to carriage return–linefeed combinations on output. "  If you think that violates the standard, argue with Microsoft, but note that [the reference at cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) also says that character conversion may occur.

Comment: (The two sentences of eryksun's you quote are only tangentially relevant to the OP, but they're not incorrect.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: "the C run time library stdio provided by Microsoft does do character conversion"* I didn't realise that Microsoft had screwed up even `stdio`, but `t` is an *invalid character* in the `mode` string for ISO C, and the call should throw an `EINVAL` error if you use it. They could at least have had an `_fopen` or similar to add custom functionality. *"The two sentences of eryksun's you quote are only tangentially relevant to the OP"* That's not true. It is ***not*** the C library that does the conversion in the OP's situation and many others, and it's irrelevant that it *can*.

Comment: @Borodin, it was relevant to point out that Windows isn't doing the conversion, since at the time the answer incorrectly claimed that it was.  Eryksun then goes on to ask whether Perl is using the Microsoft CRT to do the conversion or not.  I can see that the second sentence in the comment at issue could be misinterpreted, but it seems to me that you're making way too much of a fuss about it.  Never mind; I just wanted to make a factual correction, and that's (almost) done.

Comment: ... footnote 271 in the WG14 draft of C11 explicitly permits implementations to support additional characters in the `mode` string.  I don't know for certain how far back that goes, but I think it has always been permitted.  And of course the `b` option is explicitly listed, and without it the implementation is explicitly permitted to perform character conversion (paragraph 7.12.2.2).

Answer (score 1):

*"Actually I set unix format as notepad++ default which is my main editor"* I think you should make the effort the keep files with the correct line endings for the appropriate system. You won't make any friends if you keep Linux files everywhere, as it will make it very hard for others to work with your non-standard methodology

It isn't very hard to work with both systems properly, as all you have to do is to make the change automatically when copying from one system to another. You can use `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` when making the copy, but it would be a simple job to write a Perl program to update all of your systems with the relevant version of the text files

However, if you insist on this plan, this should help you to achieve it

By default, when running on Windows, perl will use the IO layers `:unix` and `:crlf`, which means it works the same as on a Linux system but will translate CRLF to LF on input, and LF to CRLF on output

You can make individual `open` calls behave differently by adding an explicit pseudo-layer `:raw`, which removes the `:crlf` layer. But if you want to modify the special file handles`STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `ARGV` then you need a different tactic, because those handles are opened for you by perl

You can use the [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) pragma at the top of your program, like this

```
use open IO => ':raw';
```

which will implicitly apply the `:raw` layer to every input or output file handle, including the special handles. You can set this from the command line by using

```
perl -Mopen=IO,raw program.pl
```

Or you can set the `PERLIO` environment variable

```
set PERLIO=raw
```

which will affect every program run henceforth from the same cmd window

Comment: Hi, Borodin. Thank you so much for your answer and various suggestions. But I just tried `perl -Mopen=IO,raw -i.bak -pe "s/aaa/bbb/g" test.txt` and `set PERLIO=raw && perl -i.bak -pe "s/ibrav/lll/g" 0.txt`. But they didn't work, resulted file also becomes '\r\n'.